# Removing Confirmation From Mailchimp

Tags: php, mailchimp, email-confirmation

This is the code for adding mails to mailchimp's list:

```
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://galtech.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=47b1f42d22084b5ee4606ecb8&amp;id=355af3a7a5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

When i submitting the form i got a confirmation window thats i doesnot needed.
How can discard that confirmation?
That means i does not need to display the confirmation.What i do?

Comment: You mean a new window/tab is created with "Almost finished..." that you don't want to appear?